# Does psVar[-6] refer to 6*sizeof(psVar) bytes before psVar? Can you avoid the negative index?

Tags: c, ghidra, pointer

In this decompiled code, does `psVar8[-6]` refer to `6*sizeof(psVar8) == 12` bytes before `psVar8`?

```
psVar8 = (short *)(&DAT_1412345b4 + named_index * 0x20);
do {
  if (psVar8[-6] == 0) break;
  // ...
} while (lVar10 < 6);
```

It would seem more intuitive to me if the position of `psVar8` was earlier to avoid the negative index. Is there a way to change this in the decompiled code, or a reason not to?

I'm attaching the entire loop in case that is important to the question:

```
    do {
      if (psVar8[-6] == 0) break;
      if (psVar8[-6] == 4) {
        named_variable = 0;
        if (0 < *psVar8) {
          named_variable = (int)*psVar8;
        }
        iVar4 = 0x1d;
        if (named_variable < 0x1d) {
          iVar4 = named_variable;
        }
        *(undefined2 *)(&DAT_145678900 + (longlong)iVar4 * 2) = 1;
      }
      lVar10 += 1;
      psVar8 = psVar8 + 1;
    } while (lVar10 < 6);
```

Comment: no sizeof() does not come in play it is an index into an array [look at David Heffermans Answer in this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133804/negative-array-index-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running into a case of "shifted pointers". For various reasons the compiler might generate code where a pointer to the middle of a struct is returned. There is a [Ghidra PR](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/pull/2189) for this, but this isn't merged yet and still has various issues, IDA discusses this feature [here](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1695.shtml)